# Click in CasperJS doesn't really work

Tags: javascript, click, casperjs

I try to click this button :

```
<input class="right boutonActionTableau nouveau" onclick="addPeriode()" style="margin:0 0 10px 0 !important;" type="button" value="Période">
```

My script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  false,
        loadPlugins: false
    },
    clientScripts: ["jquery.min.js"]
});

casper.start(url, function() {
    this.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X)');
    this.fill('form[action="/Login/DoLogin"]', {
        'Login': 'login',
        'Password': 'password'
    }, true);
    this.click('form[action="/Login/DoLogin"]');
});

casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
    this.echo('ok');
    this.mouseEvent('click','input[class="right boutonActionTableau nouveau"]');
    this.capture('test-screen1.png');
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('test-screen4.png');
});

casper.run();
```

I don't have error, but when i take screenshoot, my page don't change... 
In my webbrowser, this click add a form after a previous form (if i click 3 time, i have 3 other form)

If in my console chrome i type : `$(function(){addPeriode();});` it's ok...

Comment: Your script is quite strange. 1. You click after submitting the loginform. 2. At the end you use `renderResults` which is from the tester module and not from the casper module. 3. You add jquery to the page, but never use it. 4. If it works when you call `addPeriode()` in Chrome, why don't you do this in CasperJS?

Comment: It is not clear where your problem lies. What is supposed to happen when you click it and what does or doesn't happen? Please edit your question with the missing information.

Comment: 4. I do not know how ?
I have edit my ask

thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the same JavaScript as in the Chrome console when you call it inside of [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate), because it is the sandboxed window into the page.

You can either call

```
casper.evaluate(function(){
    addPeriode();
});
```

or

```
casper.evaluate(function(){
    var el = document.querySelector('input.right.boutonActionTableau.nouveau');
    el.click();
    // or
    el.onclick();
});
```

But the normal click should have worked. You can try to wait after the click.

```
casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
    this.echo('ok');
    this.click('input.right.boutonActionTableau.nouveau');
    this.capture('test-screen1.png');

}).wait(5000).then(function() {
    this.capture('test-screen4.png');
});
```

Comment: If this doesn't help, please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Yes, i try evaluate, but don't work. I don't have an event on my console. I try an echo in, but never see... Don't know why... 
I try wait too, but this is the same

Answer (score 1):

You should use `click()` instead of `mouseEvent()`, unless you have a special reason. IIRC, `mouseEvent()` requires the button being clicked to be in the current viewport, whereas click() just wants it anywhere in the page.

The second problem with your code is here:

```
input[class="right boutonActionTableau nouveau"]
```

Either use:

```
input.right.boutonActionTableau.nouveau
```

as in Artjom's answer or, if you really want the [attribute syntax](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-attribute-values/), then this way:

```
input[class*="right"][class*="boutonActionTableau"][class*="nouveau"]
```

BTW, you might find my story [in this post](http://darrendev.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/casper-d3-jquery-and-clicking.html) useful. In that case, the link (that I thought was not getting clicked) was actually fine and was getting clicked; the Ajax call involved was returning an error message which is why the screenshot never updated. But I did get to explore lots of ways to do a click!

Comment: I didn't know there was a difference between `mouseEvent('click')` and `click()`. `click() == (mouseEvent('mousedown') && mouseEvent('mouseup') && mouseEvent('click'))`, but I haven't found any evidence that it is at all viewport specific.

Comment: @ArtjomB. My memory was not quite right, as it was `mouse.click()`, not `mouseEvent` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24861718/841830 ).
It sounds like you are quoting the source code there, so I may be wrong. Or, I wonder if the mousedown/mouseup before "click" is important?

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, with page.error, i see the problem : kendoUI. casperjs load thenopen before the end of my previous action. Now it's ok like that :

```
casper.start('links.net', function() {

    this.fill('form[action="/Login/DoLogin"]', {
        'Login': 'gfdgdfg',
        'Password': 'dfgdfg'
    }, true);
    this.click('form[action="/Login/DoLogin"]');

    this.thenOpen('links2.net', function() {
    this.echo('loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooool');    
    this.click('input.right.boutonActionTableau.nouveau');
    this.capture('test-screen1.png');

})
```

My first script (doesn't work):

```
    casper.start('links.net', function() {

        this.fill('form[action="/Login/DoLogin"]', {
            'Login': 'fghfgh',
            'Password': 'fghfghfgh'
        }, true);
        this.click('form[action="/Login/DoLogin"]');


        }).wait(5000).then(function() {
            this.capture('testlol.png');
        });


    });

  casper.thenOpen('links2.net', function() {
       this.echo('loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooool');
       this.wait(10000);
       this.click('input.right.boutonActionTableau.nouveau');
       this.wait(10000);
       this.capture('test-screen1.png');

    }).wait(5000).then(function() {
        this.capture('testlol.png');
});
```

Really thanks for your help

Comment: So, what was the problem?

Comment: I have edited my answer, but my casper.thenopen was executed before the end of my first loading

Comment: This I can't believe. `casper.start(url, function(){something}).thenOpen(url, function(){something})` and `casper.start(url, function(){something; this.thenOpen(url, function(){something})})` are equivalent.

Comment: I really don't understand, now the same script of yesterday is ok... :/

Comment: Maybe it failed because you used `casper.mouseEvent` instead of `casper.click`? If yes, then you should accept Darren's answer.

Comment: Re `mouseEvent` vs. `click`, perhaps you can test it both ways and see? (I may have been thinking of something else, so will try to find out what that was.)

Comment: It was a wait. I need to take 2 secondes minimum... Now it's ok, but i have other problem... I add 3 or 4 form with my button, how can i go in last form ? Id is aleatory...

Comment: @Manolel That depends on your markup. You will need to select the for with for example an [`:nth-child`](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) selector. Ask a new question only if you run into a problem. On an unrelated note: If you want to notify somebody, you should use `@replies`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. ty ;)
Only one ask : this.click('li.k-item[unselectable="on"][text() = "Gratuit"]');

Why that is incorrect ? I look XPATH doc but i don't understand...

My objective is too take form "gratuit" when unselectable = "on" : 

<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">standard 2014</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">gratuit</li>
<li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">lol</li>

Comment: @Manolel You're mixing CSS selectors and XPath expressions. CSS has no text() function. To use Xpath expressions you need to use the xpath utility `var x=require('casper').selectXPath; this.click(x('//li[contains(@class,"k-item") and unselectable="on" and text() = "Gratuit"]'))`

Comment: I have an error : "cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector". Thank's for your help

Comment: Forgot `@` in `unselectable`: `this.click(x('//li[contains(@class,"k-item") and @unselectable="on" and text() = "Gratuit"]'))`